# Objective C Dropbox SDK v2 - Downloading File Not Found

Tags: objective-c, dropbox

Building an iOS app using objective c. I have gotten the Dropbox SDK v2 to link an account and upload a file. However when I attempt to download that same file I am being told it is not found (statuscode 409). I am using the exact code from the dropbox official sdk github. Currently I am pointing to the file location to download as /Apps/App Name/file but have tried altering the location and still no luck. Does anyone have working sample code? Thanks.

Comment: There's [an example for downloading here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#download-style-request). If something's not working as expected for you, please share the code you're using and the unexpected error/output.

Comment: Thanks Greg. You helped solve this on another thread. I now have a new problem I will be posting about.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Download-not-able-to-find-file-when-exists/m-p/318066 ]